# Weight of non-degenerate code

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

I just read (here (Theorem 1.2): http://www.jams.or.jp/scm/contents/e-2006-6/2006-52.pdf) the following statement:

If C is a non-degenerate [n,k] linear code, then it holds that $$ n = \frac{1}{q^k - q^{k-1}} \sum_{x \in C}{w(x)}$$

But why does this hold true?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, its a double counting argument.

Take the $q^k\times n$ matrix $M$ whose rows are the codewords of $C$.

Calculate the number of nonzero entries in $M$.

1) Row-wise: For the row labeled by codeword $c$, the number of nonzero entries is $w(c)$, the Hamming weight of $c$. That's easy.

2) Column-wise: As I have explained in another question, today, in each column each value from ${\Bbb F}_q$ is taken on an equal number of times. Here the prerequisite comes in that the code $C$ is non-degenerate, i.e., has no all-zero column. Then the number of nonzero values per column is $q^{k-1}(q-1)$, and we have $n$ columns.

This gives totally,
$$n (q^k-q^{k-1}) = \sum_{c\in C} w(c).$$

Comment: This helped me a lot, thank you very much! :)